# Translate and detect at same time using Google Translate API

Tags: google-translate

I want to use the google translate API to detect a language being typed and also get the translation but it seems this is not possible according to the [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language).

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or would I have to make two calls? 
Thanks

Comment: Looks you can detect and translate at the same time: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/googleLanguageR/vignettes/translation.html

Comment: Basically it will detect the source language automatically by calling the API method translate(): https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks JL-HN! It seems you only get detectedSourceLanguage back as a field if you do not supply the source as a parameter. Not sure how I missed this. I would certainly accept your comment as an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you can detect and translate your contents at the same time. To be more specific, it will detect the source language automatically without specifying the source language by simply calling the Translation API method [translate()](http://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text).

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried this out and its working great :) . I just needed to leave source out of the query url.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the translate method without specifying the source language and only specify target language. Below is code snippet of code using 
google-cloud-translate jar. It works perfect

```
    Translate translate = getTranslationServiceClient();

    // Translates some text into target language
    Translation translation = translate.translate("Hello", TranslateOption.targetLanguage("hi"));
```